# How to add a column in a table and then turn it into the primary key column and add values on SQL?

Tags: sql, for-loop, primary-key, create-table, alter

I have this table right now...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DatosLegales](
    [IdCliente] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Nombre] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [RFC] [varchar](13) NULL,
    [CURP] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [IMSS] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Calle] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Numero] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Colonia] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Pais] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Estado] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Ciudad] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CodigoPostal] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Telefono] [varchar](13) NULL,
    [TipoEmpresa] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Tipo] [varchar](20) NULL,
)
```

IdCliente is both the Primary Key (not indexable) and it is related to another table.
What I want now is to add a column named IdDatoLegal ...
I want it to become the new primary key, to become indexable, and for the records that are already added, I need to update them with the values: 1, 2, 3, 4.... till the last row...

I am starting the query but I don't know how to continue...

```
ALTER TABLE DatosLegales DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE DatosLegales ADD IdDatoLegal int;
//I guess here goes where update every row's IdDatoLegal
//Then when I specify that IdDatoLegal is indexable for future inserts
//and finally when I specify that IdDatoLegal is the new primary key
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Create another table, then copy the old one into it.

Comment: I can give you a tip. If it is SQL Server, you can use SQL Management studio to modify the table, but not saving the actual changes. Then if you open Table Designer -> Generate Change Script, it will show you the SQL script it will be using to modify the table. For complex changes it will generate a temp table. This is a good way to save time, as the management studio will do all the dirty work for you

Comment: Please tag your question with the specific SQL implementation, not just "sql". This is an area that implementations probably differ in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

select @sql = 'alter table DatosLegales drop constraint ' + quotename(name)
from sys.indexes 
where object_id = object_id('DatosLegales')
and index_id = 1

exec(@sql)

alter table  DatosLegales
add IdDatoLegal bigint not null identity(1,1) 
constraint pk_DatosLegales primary key clustered

select * from DatosLegales
```